# Numba alternative with class, yield support and z3py

Tags: python, numba, z3py

Does an alternative exist to numba that support:
- classes
- yield statements, and
- z3.

Identical support is not needed but similar optimisation will be useful.

Comment: How about Cython?

Comment: thanx will take a look at it